# Copy WordPress multisite to Mamp Pro for testing

Tags: wordpress, multisite, mamp-pro

I have inherited a WordPress multisite which is on an older version of WordPress (V 3.5). I want to test it locally and tried it on Mamp Pro version 3.5.2. I did a search and replace in the local database for the http://www.example.com and changed to http://example:8888 (the local url). I then changed the URL as well replacing it in the wp-config file. I am now getting a database error that it cannot establish a connection. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a database connection problem. You need to have the credentials to your local database in wp-config.

```
define('DB_NAME', 'your_db_name');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'your_db_user');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'your_db_password');
```